# Creating json object from POJO object in restful web service

Tags: java, json, hibernate, pojo

I am developing a web application. I have database used by the web service. I want to send the same data to the web pages which are calling web service.

I get the data i.e. single row from the database by using hibernate and POJO classes`(getColumn)`. Now I have object(POJO class) of the Table which represent single row of the database. For sending it back to the web pages (html, jsp), I need to convert it to the json object as my web service returns the json object.

How can I make Json object from POJO classes. There are many other ways to generate Json String but i want json object.
How can do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**GSon**](http://www.json.org/) to convert json object to java object

[Link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/)
to refer example.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
//to get json object use toJson
String json = gson.toJson(obj);
//to get java object use fromJson
MyClass obj = gson.fromJson(jsonObj, MyClass.class);
```

or

[jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) is also pretty fast and easy to use

Comment: Thanks swap, But i want ot make json object, toJson give the string represenation of it. I wish something like                    JSONobject jobj = xxx.(POJOobj) so JSONobject has all the kay-value ready

Comment: Once you get Json string you can covert it to Object. in java script u can use `var obj = eval("(" + jsonStr + ')');` and in java `JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr)` Using [org.json](http://json.org/java/) library

Answer (score 1):

```
private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = mapper.convertValue(YOUR POJO CLASS, JsonNode.class);
```

You can use Jackson and achieve this as above. GSON also does the job.

Answer (score 0):

The way I use is with Google's Gson library. Very simple and powerful

Answer (score 0):

Spring and Jackson as it is so simple. You can find a very basic example below [Jackson/spring JSON example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/)